# Ruby on Rails vs PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I'm going to ask you an opinion based on your experience on which is better to use for development!

i have read that Ruby on Rails is a very powerful language. Now, based on my needs, web development and iOS app development where should i be focused more?

Is it more easy to build iOS app based on php or Ruby on Rais?

Thanks..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/150789

Comment: Building an iOS app might be easier based on Objective C, I guess...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation, i just needed an opinion, based on someone experience..

Comment: Google for "gorilla vs. shark".

Answer (score 2):

first of all ruby on rails is not a language, its framework written in `ruby language` and run on `rails server`

`php` is a language not a framework,

you can use any of them but in case of `ruby on rails` its well organised `frameowrk` all security measures have been compromised beautifylly, and you will write less in it.

you can also go with php as its also a very very powerfull language especially for web development

Comment: You can't use either to develop iOS apps (at least not the client side component of said app)